# Dynamically load stylesheet in Chrome with callback

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, dynamic

http://www.phpied.com/when-is-a-stylesheet-really-loaded/

Using this solution has worked great for loading a stylesheet with a callback, except in Chrome.

In Chrome (v18) I can still see the CSS being applied, which screws up some other functions that depend on the height and width settings from the dynamically loaded CSS.

Any ideas???

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WebKit, you can poll for changes to document.styleSheets, here is a function that do that in lazyload (taken from https://github.com/rgrove/lazyload/blob/master/lazyload.js)

Or just use that plugin it does js too :)

```
function pollWebKit() {
    var css = pending.css, i;

    if (css) {
      i = styleSheets.length;

      // Look for a stylesheet matching the pending URL.
      while (--i >= 0) {
        if (styleSheets[i].href === css.urls[0]) {
          finish('css');
          break;
        }
      }

      pollCount += 1;

      if (css) {
        if (pollCount < 200) {
          setTimeout(pollWebKit, 50);
        } else {
          // We've been polling for 10 seconds and nothing's happened, which may
          // indicate that the stylesheet has been removed from the document
          // before it had a chance to load. Stop polling and finish the pending
          // request to prevent blocking further requests.
          finish('css');
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: still have some small kinks to work out in my own code, but it definitely loads the stylesheets with a correctly timed callback. thanks!